Touching dogs obstructs prayers - source?
One of the first things I learned in yeshiva was that there is some source that says that:

if one touches a dog, then their prayers are "held up in heaven" for 40 days.

I don't remember anything else, except I was pretty sure I heard a source quoted, or read it in a book, and either way IIRC I did test the idea, but was ultimately convinced that this is something worth committing to my memory and tagging as "legit".
However, to this day I have not found a source, and I would like to, if possible. Does anyone know where it is? I am particularly aiming to explore it from a halachic perspective, and failing that, seeking to at least understand what I am supposed to take from it, practically.
So, anything that helps with that is also welcome and likely to score a quick checkmark. Lack of response will likely lead me to conclude that there is no source (and I might start to question my sanity instead)

I recall learning the same thing about looking at a cross.  Can't seem to place the source right now.

I've seen people make the same claim, but nowhere with a source
